# Using a flag in a Makefile target

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have a Makefile like this:

```
(more Makefile code)

%_dev.pdf: %.csv
    # do stuff that

%_prod.pdf: %.csv
    # do stuff
```

I like to have a quick dev run and a longer prod run. The code above reflects that. However, it leads to redundant code. So I would like to do something like this:

```
MODE?=dev

%_$(MODE).pdf: %.csv
    # do stuff
```

Is this valid? It seems that I am mixing different concepts and might run into problems. What is the preferred way to implement some kind of switch in targets?

Comment: you could add a phony target and let it handle the common part. That would eliminate the duplicate code

Comment: The question is "how redundant?". Apply the usual separation of concern techniques you are using when programming other languages: is there a common sub-process that can stand as a target in its own right? If there is no file which gets procuded, maybe `.PHONY` can act as a target mediating the functionality? If the code is really really complex, maybe a [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) is a viable solution

Comment: For big `make` programs one may want to summon a helper library like [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) to overcome some complexities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid.

Instead of dealing with suffixes you can just build into another directory:

```
MODE := dev # Immediate assignment, make MODE=prod overrides it.
build_dir := ${MODE}

${build_dir}/%.pdf : %.csv | ${build_dir}
    # commands

${build_dir} :
    mkdir -p $@
```